# Assignment of one struct to other struct of "structural identical" type

Tags: go

My problem is like this: I have a `MyMail` package which provides a function `SendMail(MyMail.Mail)` to other packages. `MyMail` uses the package `LowLevelMail` and its function `Send(LowLevelMail.Mail)` to actually send Mails. `MyMail.Mail` and `LowLevelMail.Mail` are identical in the sense that they define the "same struct" (i.e. equally named and typed fields).

`SendMail(m MyMail.Mail)` has to convert `m` to `LowLevelMail.Mail` before using `Send(LowLevelMail.Mail`. `newmail := LowLevelMail.Mail(m)` won't work. But this could be possible as the compiler should be able to see that the fields of the two structs are identical. Maybe it's not a good idea to support this because of not exported fields.

1) Can I somehow assign `m` to `newmail` without doing it all by hand (and without losing all type safety?)? The by hand method would cause some pain (the struct does not solely consist of simple types which can be assigned to the other struct's).

2) Is there a better solution to the whole problem (i.e. "I don't want to use other packages' types in my API because I don't want my packages' clients to depend on a foreign API. This foreign API may change or I might decide at some point to not use it any more.").

**Update**: I missed an important point: `LowLevelMail.Mail` has a field of type `LowLevelMail.Address` which also is "redefined" in `MyMail` as `MyMail.Address`.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
type T1 struct {
    a int
    b string
}
type T2 struct {
    a int
    b string
}
func main() {
    t1 := T1{2, "test"}
    t2 := T2(t1)
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

Isn't it what you're looking for ?

If your question is about how to do this when T1 and T2 are in different packages and don't export their fields, well, allowing this would simply nullify the privacy of those fields so of course that's not possible.

Comment: I can do it by hand so the compiler could too. It could simply ignore hidden fields.

Comment: For not trivial conversions like this, I think a `constructor` taking the value of the other type as parameter would be much cleaner than asking for an implicit and magical copy&conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be something like this:

```
package lowlevelmail

type Mail struct { P int; p int}

func Send(m Mail) { }
```

and

```
package mymail

import "lowlevelmail"

type Mail lowlevelmail.Mail

func Send(m Mail) { lowlevelmail.Send(lowlevelmail.Mail(m)) }
```

and

```
package main

import "mymail"

func main() {var m mymail.Mail; mymail.Send(m)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this won't work for me. See my update in the question.